# How to Bibtex: one author, "in association with" another author

Tags: bibtex

I run into this reference:

> Wold, H., in association with L. Jureen, Demand Analysis. A study in
>   econometrics. Stockholm, Geber, 1952. New York, J. Wiley and Sons,
>   1953.

The "in association with" part trips me over. How can I make a proper BibTeX entry for this please?

---

**Edit**: I use the `ecta` style:

```
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
```

My bibliography looks like this:

[image]

and when I cite the first entry above, the output looks like `Wold (1945)`.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use? And, how should citation callouts look like (assuming the citation style isn't numeric)?

Comment: @Mico: I edited to answer your questions. Thank you.

Comment: So, should the citation call-out look like "Wald (1952)", or should it like "Wald and Jureen (1952)"? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico: I honestly don't know which is appropriate. Can you please provide both solutions and I'll decide on which later? Thanks again.

Comment: I've posted an answer with two possible solutions. Your choice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must confess I'm not sure what the precise status may be of a person who is listed as a "collaborator": Is Lars a full co-author or is he just a minor contributor? If it's the latter, why even list Lars next to the main author? Maybe to get around the awkwardness of having to justify why the authors' names aren't sorted alphabetically? I truly don't know.

For your bibliography, I think you have two choices; you'll have to make the call. First, you could treat Lars as an ordinary co-author. This'll also mean that citation call-outs will be of the form "Wold and Juréen (19xx). Or, use the `\relax` trick -- actually, it's a very well documented trick and hence not really dirty... -- to make BibTeX believe that "in collaboration with L. Juréen" is just a particularly long sequence of Herman's given names. If you choose this approach, the citation call-out will look like "Wold (19xx)".

Both solutions are shown below. Happy BibTeXing!

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{wold:1952,
  author   = "Wold, Herman and Lars Jur{\'e}en",
  title    = "Demand Analysis: A Study in Econometrics",
  year     = 1952,
  address  = "Stockholm",
  publisher= "Geber",
}
@book{wold:1953,
  author   = "Wold, Herman {\relax in collaboration with L. Jur{\'e}en}",
  title    = "Demand Analysis: A Study in Econometrics",
  year     = 1953,
  address  = "New York",
  publisher= "John Wiley and Son, Inc.",
}
\end{filecontents} 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\begin{document}
\citet{wold:1952}, \citet{wold:1953}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you need to insert a comma between the first author's name and the "`in collaboration with <other author>`" string, set up the author field as follows:

```
  author   = "Wold, Herman {\relax\unskip, in collaboration with L. Jur{\'e}en}",
```

[image]

Observe the use of `\unskip` immediately before `,`. The `\unskip` directive serves to suppress the space that would otherwise be inserted by LaTeX.

Comment: What an amazing answer. Thank you and I also enjoy reading your thoughts.

Comment: @yurnero -- Wow, many thanks for the compliment!! I've posted an addendum to mention how to achieve the "comma effect" -- the comma between "Wold, H." and "In collaboration with..." -- that was featured in your query.